# geoserver.catalog.FailedRequestError: Tried to make a GET request to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspaces.xml but got a 404 status code

Tags: geoserver, python-3, gsconfig

I'm trying connect to geoserver via rest protocol by gsconfig-py3 in python3 ,I get this error, but when I type "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest" in  browser I can see these items moreover when I click on each of them I can see content of them:

for more information I'm using:

OS LMDE 3 X64 (Debian 9),
GeoServer 2.15.0,
Python version:3.7.3

**Geoserver Configuration API**

- about/manifest
- about/status
- about/version
- fonts
- index
- layergroups
- layers
- namespaces
- resource
- security/acl/catalog
- security/acl/layers
- security/acl/rest
- security/acl/services
- security/masterpw
- security/roles
- security/self/password
- security/usergroup/groups
- security/usergroup/users
- services/wcs/settings
- services/wfs/settings
- services/wms/settings
- settings
- settings/contact
- styles
- templates
- workspaces

But when I try connect to geoserver via gsconfig-py3
for example below code:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest", username='admin', password='geoserver')
topp=cat.get_workspace("topp")
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/killercode/Desktop/test_version.py", line 3, in <module>
    topp=cat.get_workspace("topp")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geoserver/catalog.py", line 945, in get_workspace
    candidates = [w for w in self.get_workspaces() if w.name == name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geoserver/catalog.py", line 940, in get_workspaces
    description = self.get_xml(rest_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geoserver/catalog.py", line 158, in get_xml
    text
geoserver.catalog.FailedRequestError: Tried to make a GET request to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspaces.xml but got a 404 status code: 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /geoserver/workspaces.xml. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.12.v20180830</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

How I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that `gsconfig-py3` is less relaxed about the format of the base URL than `gsconfig` was. If it doesn't end `/` it doesn't think to add one for you. so

```
cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/", username='admin', password='geoserver')
```

does work.

I would raise an issue and a fix for this if I was you.

Comment: yes, you'd right when I add / I didn't get error, thank you

Comment: I'm trying to connect in the same way, with that line above, and if I do print(cat.__dict__) I get:
 {'_service_url': 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/', '_session': <requests.sessions.Session object at 0x7f4658408ef0>, '_cache': {}, '_disable_ssl_validation': False, '_username': 'admin', '_version': None, '_password': 'geoserver'}.
But if I try to do cat.get_workspace("my_workspace") I get a ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused. Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: To make it work I had to use the URL "http://geoserver:8080/geoserver/rest/"